# Why is stat() returning EFAULT?

Tags: c, named-pipes, stat, errno, mkfifo

I'm writing a program that when run from two separate bash sessions as two separate processes, opens a named pipe between the two to allow strings to be sent from one to the other.

When the process is first executed from one terminal, it checks `stat(fname, buf) == -1` to see if a file at path `fname` exists and if not, creates it. The process then assumes that since it was the one to make the `FIFO`, it is the one that will be sending messages through it and continues accordingly.

After that occurs, the program can then be run from another terminal that should determine that it will be the receiver of messages through the pipe by checking `stat(fname, buf) == -1`. The condition should return false now, and `stat(fname, buf)` itself should return `0` because there exists a file at `fname` now.

But for reasons I am unable to discern, when the second process is run, `stat(fname, buf)` still returns `-1`. The variable `errno` is set to `EFAULT`. The `man` page for `stat()` only decribes `EFAULT` as "Bad address." Any help determining why the error occurs or what is meant by "Bad address." would be greaty appreciated.

I've verified that the file is indeed created by the first process as intended. The first process waits at the line `pipe = open(fname, O_WRONLY);` because it can't continue until the other end of `pipe` is opened.

Edit: The following is a self-contained implementation of my code. I have confirmed that it compiles and experiences the problem I described here.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include    <string.h>

#define MAX_LINE 80
#define oops(m,x)   { perror(m); exit(x); }

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    char line[MAX_LINE];
    int pipe, pitcher, catcher, initPitcher, quit;
    struct stat* buf;

    char* fname = "/tmp/absFIFOO";
    initPitcher = catcher = pitcher = quit = 0;

    while (!quit) { 
        if (((!pitcher && !catcher && stat(fname, buf) == -1) || pitcher) && !quit) {
            // Then file does not exist
            if (errno == ENOENT) {
                // printf("We're in the file does not exist part\n");
                if (!pitcher && !catcher) {
                    // Then this must be the first time we're running the program. This process will take care of the unlink().
                    initPitcher = 1;
                    int stat;
                    if (stat = mkfifo(fname, 0600) < 0)
                        oops("Cannot make FIFO", stat);
                }
                pitcher = 1;

                // open a named pipe
                pipe = open(fname, O_WRONLY);

                printf("Enter line: ");
                fgets(line, MAX_LINE, stdin);

                if (!strcmp(line, "quit\n")) {
                    quit = 1;
                }

                // actually write out the data and close the pipe
                write(pipe, line, strlen(line));
                close(pipe); 
            }
        } else if (((!pitcher && !catcher) || catcher) && !quit) {
            // The first condition is just a check to see if this is the first time we've run the program. We could check if stat(...) == 0, but that would be unnecessary
            catcher = 1;

            pipe = open("/tmp/absFIFO", O_RDONLY);

            // set the mode to blocking (note '~')
            int flags;
            flags &= ~O_NONBLOCK;
            fcntl(pipe, F_SETFL, flags); //what does this do?

            // read the data from the pipe
            read(pipe, line, MAX_LINE);

            if (!strcmp(line, "quit\n")) {
                quit = 1;
            }

            printf("Received line: %s\n", line);

            // close the pipe
            close(pipe);
        }
    }
    if (initPitcher)
        unlink(fname);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Show the code in question, preferably in a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org). This doesn't sound like it would take much code to repro.

Comment: EFAULT most likely means that either `fname` or `buf` are invalid pointers.

Comment: Furthermore using `stat` this way isn't a great way to check if a file exists. You're opening yourself up to [TOCTOU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use) races.

Comment: @WhozCraig I have presented my code as requested.

Comment: Why the downvote? I presented my code as requested and I believe I have shown that I have done a good deal of research into the problem, I have presented my problem clearly, and the problem could potentially be useful to others.

Comment: As the question currently appears, I don't see why it was downvoted nor why there is a request to close as not programming related.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have this piece of code:

```
struct stat* buf;
...
if (((!pitcher && !catcher && stat(fname, buf) == -1)
```

When you call `stat()`, buf isn't initalized and there's no telling what it points to.

You must allocate some storage for it, so `stat()` has a valid place to store the result.
The easiest thing is to just allocate it on the stack:

```
struct stat buf;
...
if (((!pitcher && !catcher && stat(fname, &buf) == -1)
```

Comment: Presumably as it doesn't return `EFAULT` for the first run, `stat` checks if the file exists before checking the pointer. That seems backwards to me (I'd do the parameter checks first, and anything which doesn't hit the file system before stuff that does), but this random implementation of stat behaves like that http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/source/linux/fs/stat.c

Comment: Thank you very much! I see now, and I imagine I should do the same for `fname` so that its space gets allocated. I'm still new to pointers. A segfault would have tipped me off to this.

Comment: @user110524 fname is ok. You have a string literal, and you make fname point to the start of that string literal, which is ok. (though since you cannot change a string literal, you could make it const: const char *fname ="/tmp/absFIFOO"; )

Answer (score 0):

You have not shown your code, but `EFAULT` means 'bad address'. This indicates that you have not properly allocated (or passed) your buffer for `stat` or the filename (`fname`).

Answer (score 0):

`buf` isn't initialised anywhere. What exactly do you expect to happen?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I would have expected a segfault. I have no idea why this doesn't cause one now.

Comment: @anthonybrice You do get a segfault on GNU/Hurd systems (a good thing IMO).